# What is more clever to determine linear independence of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

In our course we discussed the following method to determine if given vectors are linear independent:

write each vector as a column of a homogenous matrix and evaluate if the matrix can be solved with a unique solution.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&1&2&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

But as far is I know I can only determine if a bunch of vectors is linear dependent/independent but I can not determine **which** of those are linear dependent. (note: Of course this example has  a trivial, clear to see answer, but it could be not that obvious)

However if I use a different method by just writing each vector as a row:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0\\
  0&1\\
   0&2
\end{array}
\right] $$

I can easily try to reduce rows and can determine **which** vectors are linear independent. 
Is that true or am I missing some huge information so far?

Comment: A vector is not "linearly dependent" on other vectors.  A set of vectors (as set) may be linearly dependent or not.

Comment: Write each vector as a column in a matrix and row reduce it. If you are left with fewer pivots than columns, then the set of vectors is linearly dependent, and vice versa.

Comment: In this example the third vector can be expressed as 2 times the second one or the second one as half the third, while the first one is not related to the other two at all - I thought that this would be necessary information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you’ve gotten it backwards. Elementary row operations preserve linear dependency relationships among the *columns* of a matrix, not its rows. The fact that relationships among rows aren’t preserved should be pretty obvious from the echelon form: all of the dependent (zero) rows end up at the bottom regardless of which of the original rows are dependent on others. Consider, for example, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

So, assembling the vectors into a matrix as columns will let you pick out a linearly-independent subset of them that span the original set: the pivot columns of the reduced matrix tell you which those are. This won’t give you all possible independent subsets, though you can rearrange the vectors and re-reduce if you really want to do that.

On the other hand, assembling them into rows and reducing that matrix will give you a “nice” basis for their span, but in general it will consist of new vectors that weren’t in the original set.